# If I submit a new build while "waiting for review", do I go to the back of the line?

Tags: app-store-connect

Lets say I have a build uploaded to iTunes Connect that has had a status of "Waiting for Review" for 10 days. If I submit a new build will my app go to the back of the line and have to wait another 10+ days or will I still be in line to get reviewed very soon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, after you Reject Binary then upload a new one, this puts your app to the back of the line again.

Edit: see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167059/7452), [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180249/7452), the later answer on this question and [Apple's own dev guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html).

> Removing a build removes your app version from Apple’s review queue and changes its status to Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your app, the review process starts over from the beginning.

I've also experienced it myself, although that was years ago.

Comment: Can someone confirm this or provide proof so I can mark this answer as correct?

Comment: Apple's own website says 90% of apps get approved in 48 hours. It therefore stands to reason that if your app hasn't been approved in over 3 days it would be in one's best interest to self-reject and re-submit as it would have a 90% chance of being approved in 48 hours.

Answer (score 2):

If you reject your binary, you will remove your app from the Review queue. If you then submit a new build, you will unfortunately be placed at the end of the line.

We know this from experience, and it's also indicated by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34) (emphasis mine):

> Removing a build removes your app version from Apple’s review queue and changes its status to Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your app, the review process **starts over from the beginning**.

Comment: If 90% of apps get reviewed in 48 hours supposedly if you reject and resubmit you have a 90% chance of it getting reviewed in 48 hours, assuming it got stuck due to a silent failure